# Power BI if value then select columnA else columnB

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have an Excel sheet which looks like this:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
A      Val1   Val2   Val3
B      Val4   Val5   Val6
```

and another one

```
lang
de
en
es
```

Col2, Col3 and Col4 are language dependent.
What I would like to have in Power BI is if I select a value for `lang` a specific column should be displayed in the dashboard.

So something like

```
lang = de -> Col1 and Col2 
lang = en -> Col1 and Col3 
lang = es -> Col1 and Col4
```

how can I acchieve this?

Comment: unfortunatelly not... I don't need a aggregation... Just want to display the columns

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that DAX is a language dedicated to analysis but here is a workaround to your request :

You need to create a measure :

```
SelectedValue = 
VAR SelectedLang = SELECTEDVALUE(LanguageTable[lang])
RETURN
SWITCH(
    SelectedLang,
    "de", SELECTEDVALUE(DataTable[Col2]),
    "en", SELECTEDVALUE(DataTable[Col3]),
    "es", SELECTEDVALUE(DataTable[Col4]),
    BLANK()
)
```

Here you check the selected language and then return the value from the corresponding column using SELECTEDVALUE and SWITCH to return the appropriate column value based on the selected language.

To display the name of the column I created another measure and I put in a card and tried to adjust it to the table :

```
SelectedColumnName = 
VAR SelectedLang = SELECTEDVALUE(LanguageTable[lang], "default")
RETURN
SWITCH(
    SelectedLang,
    "de", "Col2",
    "en", "Col3",
    "es", "Col4",
    "default"
)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]